# Air travel while pregnant

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, british-airways, jet-airways, saudi-airlines

An Indian citizen, who is six months pregnant, is travelling with her spouse. They both hold PR status in Canada.

Their preferred airlines for a journey from India to Canada are Saudi Airlines, Jet Airways, and British Airways.

Do these airlines allow pregnant woman to travel from India to Canada?

Answer (score 18):

Since there are no Visa issues in this case, the only thing left to wonder is whether the airlines will allow her to board or not. That depends upon each airline so you have to individually go through their own terms to see.

It looks like 32 weeks is generally the limit but this is not something that can be generalized. For medical conditions different airlines have different rules so you can't safely assume 32 weeks will be fine everywhere.

**[Saudi Airlines](https://www.saudia.com/TRAVEL-WITH-SAUDIA/Special-Travel-Needs/Medical-Conditions)**: Generally fine in this case

> ACCEPTANCE OF PREGNANT PASSENGERS It is the duty of pregnant
>   passengers to advise " Saudia " of the progress of their pregnancy at
>   the point of booking of seat and at the check-in counter. The carriage
>   of pregnant passengers is subject to the following conditions:
>
> Pregnant ladies are authorized to travel up to the 8th month without
>   medical clearance. Medical clearance will be required if:
>
> Child birth is expected in less than 4 weeks.
>
> Uncertainty exists over the progress of the pregnancy and the date of delivery.
>
> . There were previous multiple births child birth complications are expected.
>
> . The medical certificate must be issued within 10 days of the flight date.
>
> . The lady will be refused carriage if the pregnancy is 35 weeks and above.
>
> .  After week (32) of her pregnancy, the pregnant woman should provide a
>   medical certificate (MEDIF) filled in by a competent doctor. The form
>   is valid for a period of (10) days from the date of issue.

---

**[Jet Airways](https://www.jetairways.com/en/in/travelinformation/expectant-mothers.aspx)**  Generally fine in this case

> - Up to 28 weeks
>
>   - Expectant mother may be accepted for travel provided that there are no prior complications.
>   - Fitness to fly certificate from her treating obstetrician and the Company Medical Department clearance is **not** required.
> - Between 29 up to 35 weeks
>
>   - Expectant mother with **uncomplicated single pregnancy*** may be accepted for travel provided she is in possession of a fitness to fly certificate from her treating obstetrician, specifying the number of weeks of pregnancy; Company Medical Department clearance is **not** required.
>   - Cases of **multiple pregnancy / complicated single** pregnancy are accepted till the end of the **32 week**, provided she is in possession of fitness to fly certificate from her treating obstetrician. The Company Medical Department clearance is also required.
> - After 35 weeks
>
>   - Not allowed

---

**[British Airways](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/travel-assistance/medical-conditions-and-pregnancy)** Generally fine in this case

> **Travelling when you're pregnant**
>
> For your and your baby’s safety you cannot fly after:
>
> - the end of the 36th week if you are pregnant with one baby
> - the end of the 32nd week if you are pregnant with more than one baby   After 28 weeks you must carry a confirmation from your doctor
>     or midwife, such as a letter or certificate, in addition to your
>     pregnancy record. This should be written within 7-10 days prior to
>     travel and confirm your approximate due date, that you're fit to
>     travel and that there are no complications with your pregnancy.
>
> This letter covers you for your entire journey, unless there are any
>   complications with your pregnancy that requires medical intervention.
>   Only then, would you be required to obtain an updated letter from the
>   doctor that treated you.